# Remove duplicate element from list of list using python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am running the below code to remove duplicates from the element list of the list
I am trying to remove element one by one from x = [['510','511','512'],['510','515','516']] when successfully removing element '515' and '516' final list will be x =[['510','511','512'],['510']]
but 510 occured in x[0] so removed x[1] from list

```
remove_element = '515'
x = [['510','511','512'],['510','515','516']]
for i in x:
   if remove_element in i:
       i.remove(remove_element)
print(x)
```

Once final list [['510','511','512'],['510']]
then remove list [['510','511','512']]

Comment: You should tak 5 more minutes to explain what you are doing, and what you do expect as final results.

Comment: sorry not able to understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You could first remove 515 as you have, and then loop through the contents of x[0] separately:

```
remove_element = '515'
x = [['510','511','512'],['510','515','516']]
for i in x:
   if remove_element in i:
       i .remove( remove_element )

for element in x[0]:  ##  ['510','511','512']
   if element in x[1]:  ##  ['510','515','516']
       x[1] .remove( element )

print(x)
```

---

or combine them into your remove list, then loop once:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

remove = ['515']  ##  make this a list
x = [['510','511','512'],['510','515','516']]

##  add initial group of elements to your remove list
remove += x[0]  ##  ['515','510','511','512']

for element in remove:  ##  loop through list
   if element in x[1]:  ##  scan for duplicates
       x[1] .remove( element )

print(x)
```

> [['510', '511', '512'], ['516']]